# In Shopify what code do I need and where to redirect from the home page to another page?

Tags: html, shopify

My website is not ready and I want to redirect users who type in my home page automatically to a landing page on Shopify. Which file and what code to I add to all me to route from www.website.com to www.website.com/landing-page automatically?

Answer (score 0):

```
{%- if template = 'index' -%}
  <script>location.href = '/landing-page';</script>
{%- endif -%}
```